# Android menu icon w/o action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My app has an extended menu and has been working on all legit devices from Android 2.1 up thru 4.1. For R11+, to save screen space, I do not display the Action Bar on "normal" screens, but do on "large" and "xlarge". With the Action Bar present, the menu icon is on the Action Bar in the upper right corner; on normal-size screens, without hardkeys, it is at the lower right in the bar with the Home and Back buttons. This is functioning as expected on the latest phones and tablets.

Now I've had two customers with some sort of direct-from-China-on-eBay 7" tablet running Android 4.0.4 who are not seeing either the Action Bar or the menu icon in the Home/Back bar. I see two malfunctions here: first, that it must be reporting its screen as "normal" since it's using the "NoActionBar" theme; and secondly that it's not then showing the menu icon in the bottom bar. The users state that this device has access to Google Play, so I assume it's an approved device.

Has anyone run into anything like this? The only solution I can see -- since I don't want to activate the Action Bar on everyone's smartphone -- is to add a settings option to display the Action Bar. Any other ideas?

Comment: "The users state that this device has access to Google Play, so I assume it's an approved device" -- that is not a valid assumption, as the Play Store gets pirated all the time. "The only solution I can see -- since I don't want to activate the Action Bar on everyone's smartphone -- is to add a settings option to display the Action Bar" -- except that, to activate the settings option, they will need the action bar to get to the menu. IMHO, either use the action bar all of the time, or don't use it at all and implement your own in-UI "menu" system.

Comment: Good point about needing a menu icon to get to the settings! I decided to always provide the Action Bar, but had to do some layout revisions to make up for the loss of screen real estate when in landscape mode on a smaller (e.g. smartphone) device.

Comment: Consider this question closed.